# Event when using keyboard for select

Tags: jquery, events, keyboard, html-select

Please help

I have a

```
<select id="select">
  <option></option>
  <option></option>
  <option></option>
<select>
```

I used jquery to detect arrow up/arrow down for select and it worked

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#select', function () {
    console.log('key-up');
});
```

But I clicked on select and a dropdown is opened, I used arrow up/arrow down to select in that drop-down but this function above not work!
I changed it to:

```
$(document).on('keyup', '#select option', function () {
    console.log('key-up');
});
```

But it not work?
**How can i detect event in this case**

Comment: See [Check if select is displaying options](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30729795/924299) and [jQuery keypress/keyup/etc events not fired when select box is expanded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648990/jquery-keypress-keyup-etc-events-not-fired-when-select-box-is-expanded).

Answer (score 0):

i think that what you want is:

```
$('#select').on('keyup', function(event) {
    if(event.which === 38) { // arrow up
       // do what you want
    }
    if(event.which === 40) { // arrow down
       // do what you want
    }
});
```